# Why is my do-while loop breaking too early in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

So my issue is while this runs, as soon as you input one it will only print the next switch and ends program without allowing input of the next choices. Here is what I have done so far.

1. I had taken the while(choice == 1) and put that in the case 1.
2. I had taken the while(choice == 1) and just used the switch with
   in a switch and used continue statement.
3. When i take out the last two breaks, i get the
   infinity loop.

Any hints on what i am doing on would be helpful.

```
package Spook;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class House {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void p(String I) {
        System.out.println(I);
    }

    public void game() {

        p("\nWelcome To Spook House, were all Spooks will haunt you.");

        do {
            p("\nPlease make your selection");
            p("         1.  Enter House for some Scares.");
            p("         2. Too Scared to Enter.");
            p("         3. Really Scared Please let me exit.");
            p("Choose one please.");

            char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

            switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    p("\nAs prepare to enter the house, The door slowly creaks open.");
                    p("\nYou enter the house and the door slams shut.");
                    p("What do you do????");
                    p("         1. Try to open the door.");
                    p("         2. Find the nearist closet and hide.");
                    p("         3. Continue onward.");
                    p("         4. Faint and end game.");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    p("\nWhat are you a chicken, Just press 1!!!!!");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    p("\nFine you win chicken, now ending.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
            while (choice == '1') {
                switch (choice) {
                    case '1':
                        p("\nAs you twist the door knoob and try to pull it open. You feel a gust of wind that pushes you down.");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        p("\nYou run towards the closet hoping to hide till daylight.");
                        p("You start to shake and laugh nerviously.");
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        p("\nYou explore the first room.");
                        p("You see an old crooked picture of a scary clown.");
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        p("\nYou have been easily to SPOOKED MMMMUUUUHHHHAAAAHHAAAA!!!!!");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: Just a minor thing, "were all" should be "where all". "As prepare to enter" should be "As you prepare to enter". "nearist" should be "nearest". "nerviously" should be "nervously". :-)

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging your code? Those 3 breaks in 3 consecutive lines smell trouble.

Comment: Hint: look at your break statements. Correlate them with your loop and switches and see which break statement breaks out of what.

Comment: Thank you for those that commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try using break inside if condition it should work fine

Example :

```
if(choice == '4')
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
```

could be written as

```
                    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line of code where you ask the user for the next input. 
Try this:

```
switch (choice) {
            case '1':
                p("\nAs prepare to enter the house, The door slowly creaks open.");
                p("\nYou enter the house and the door slams shut.");
                p("What do you do????");
                p("         1. Try to open the door.");
                p("         2. Find the nearist closet and hide.");
                p("         3. Continue onward.");
                p("         4. Faint and end game.");
                choice = in.next().charAt(0);
                break;
```

With this line the user is asked once again for input and after that the application terminates.

Comment: Funny thing is I had the choice. but for some reason when i went to copy it i must of deleted it when i was trying to get the code box to show. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

So what your code does, is it prints the first textblock with the "Please make your selection" and the 3 options. Then you grab the user input (so the `'1'`).

It enters the first switch statement and goes into `case '1'`. It prints what it needs to and breaks out of that switch statement.

Then you go into the `while (choice == '1')` loop. Here you enter the second `switch case` immediantaly without waiting and grabbing a new input.
Because you don't wait and grab a new input, the value of `choice` is still `'1'`.

Therefor in the second `switch case` you enter `case '1'` right away.
In that case it prints what it needs to print. Then you break out of that `switch case`, break out of the `while (choice == '1')` loop and lastly break out of the `do while` loop.

Comment: Thank you this really helped and turned out to be 90 percent of the issue.